# ImgButton : How to tell SmartGWT to not concatene state on the name of file source?

Tags: gwt, state, smartgwt

```
private ImgButton button = new ImgButton();

...

button.setSrc("iconName.jpg");
```

GWT or SmartGWT, I cannot tell exactly, generate state word to concatene it on the name of file.

Example to clarify :

- On focus, `iconName.jpg` become `iconName_Focus.jpg`
- On mouse down click, `iconName.jpg` become `iconName_Down.jpg`
- On over, `iconName.jpg` become `iconName_Over.jpg`

Because these images are custom images, I want to tell GWT to take a default image when I didn't provide the corresponding image.

For example, when over event is fire and `iconName_Over.jpg` does not exist then use `iconName.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the setShow{State} or setShow{State}Icon methods accordingly. For example for disabling the mouse down state, use setShowDown(Boolean.FALSE). For not showing a different icon when the mouse goes down on the button, use the setShowDownIcon(Boolean.FALSE). The rest of the actions have accordingly named methods you can look up at the ImgButton's javadoc page.